# Not able to receive socket data sent from client 1 to server and back to client 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, electron

I'm having some trouble using sockets to connect an electron app to an node(express) website hosted on heroku.

Basically I have 2 clients, for simplicity I'm going to call them teacher and student. So teacher sends data to express and express has to send the data back to student. Since a socket has to be opened from the client side, I'm thus sending a ping to express from student with some dummy data to get the socket connected and then broadcasting the data from express.

### What I have tried

**teacher and student are in the same app/ teacher is not used when student is used and vice versa**

```
function pingServer() {
  socket.emit("givebackinfo", "sendinfo");
  setTimeout(pingServer, 5);
}

ipcMain.on("serverPing:getbackinfo", function (E, item) {
  console.log(item);
  if (item == "returninfo") {
    socket.emit("givebackinfo", "sendinfo");
    // pingServer()
  } else {
    console.log("error");}
});
// receive data from express
socket.on("datareturns", (msg) => {
  console.log(msg);
  mainWindow.webContents.send("RedrawData", msg);
});
```

### The Issue

**In express I receive the "sendinfo" but I'm not able to send data back to the client that pinged it**

**express**

```
rowDelivered = 0;

// Connection for students => sends back relevant data
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('datareturns', "returns");
    socket.on('givebackinfo', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg)
        socket.broadcast.emit('datareturns', "returns");
        // socket.emit('datareturns', "sendinfo returns")
        if (msg != "sendinfo") {
            (knex('test').where('id', '>', rowDelivered).then((data) => {
                // console.log(data);

                // console.log(rowDelivered);
                if (data.length >= 1) {
                    console.log(data)
                    socket.broadcast.emit('datareturns', data);
                } else {
                    // statement
                }
            })).then(() => {
                knex('test').max('id').then((maxId) => {
                    rowDelivered = maxId[0].max
                });
            })

        } else {
            socket.broadcast.emit("datareturns", "value wrong for redraw data");
        }
    });
});
```